# Why IBM Watson Assistant Complex object properties do not update?

Tags: json, object, ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

According to the documentation **"If the context variable is a complex type such as JSON object, a JSON merge procedure is used to update the variable. The merge operation adds any newly defined properties and overwrites any existing properties of the object."** . but when I try that it does not work.

Code in a node:

```
    "context": {
         "comp_obj": "{a:1,b:2}" 
  }
```

Code in the very next node:

```
    "context": {
        "comp_obj": "{a:3}"
  }
```

But when I check values with **Manage Context** it shows `$comp_obj = "{a:3}"` and not `"{a:3, b:2}"` , So do I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you have defined your value as a string not a JSON object.

Change: `"{a:1,b:2}"` to: `{"a":1, "b":2}` and it should work fine.